# C# BitConverter Single Conversion Error

Tags: c#, bitconverter

I have a requirement to be able to parse a special NaN byte array to determine a specific condition.  The array is 0x0000A07F.  However, when I run this through BitConverter and cast to a float and then back to a byte array, the conversion does not match.

```
private void testNan()
{
    Single tf;
    Byte[] to;
    Byte[] ti;

    // Normal NaN
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    Debug.Write("Normal  NaN: 0x");
    tf = Single.NaN;
    to = BitConverter.GetBytes(tf);
    foreach (var cb in to)
        Debug.Write(cb.ToString("X2"));

    // Special NaN
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    Debug.Write("Special NaN: 0x");
    ti = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x7F }; // Special Array
    tf = BitConverter.ToSingle(ti, 0); // Float Conversion
    to = BitConverter.GetBytes(tf); // Byte Conversion
    foreach (var cb in to)
        Debug.Write(cb.ToString("X2"));

    // Iterate Conversion (3rd Byte)
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    Debug.WriteLine("Test Conversions");
    for (var count = 0; count < 256; count++)
    {
        ti = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, (byte) count, 0x7F };
        tf = BitConverter.ToSingle(ti, 0);
        to = BitConverter.GetBytes(tf);
        var pass = true;
        for (var subCount = 0; subCount < 4; subCount++)
            if (ti[subCount] != to[subCount]) pass = false;
        if (pass) continue;
        Debug.Write("FAIL [0x" + count.ToString("X2") + "]:  ");
        Debug.Write("IN=0x");
        foreach (var cb in ti)
            Debug.Write(cb.ToString("X2"));
        Debug.Write("  OUT=0x");
        foreach (var cb in to)
            Debug.Write(cb.ToString("X2"));
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
}

//Normal  NaN: 0x0000C0FF
//Special NaN: 0x0000E07F
//Test Conversions
//FAIL [0x81]:  IN=0x0000817F  OUT=0x0000C17F
//FAIL [0x82]:  IN=0x0000827F  OUT=0x0000C27F
//FAIL [0x83]:  IN=0x0000837F  OUT=0x0000C37F
//FAIL [0x84]:  IN=0x0000847F  OUT=0x0000C47F
//FAIL [0x85]:  IN=0x0000857F  OUT=0x0000C57F
//FAIL [0x86]:  IN=0x0000867F  OUT=0x0000C67F
//FAIL [0x87]:  IN=0x0000877F  OUT=0x0000C77F
//FAIL [0x88]:  IN=0x0000887F  OUT=0x0000C87F
//FAIL [0x89]:  IN=0x0000897F  OUT=0x0000C97F
//FAIL [0x8A]:  IN=0x00008A7F  OUT=0x0000CA7F
//FAIL [0x8B]:  IN=0x00008B7F  OUT=0x0000CB7F
//FAIL [0x8C]:  IN=0x00008C7F  OUT=0x0000CC7F
//FAIL [0x8D]:  IN=0x00008D7F  OUT=0x0000CD7F
//FAIL [0x8E]:  IN=0x00008E7F  OUT=0x0000CE7F
//FAIL [0x8F]:  IN=0x00008F7F  OUT=0x0000CF7F
//FAIL [0x90]:  IN=0x0000907F  OUT=0x0000D07F
//FAIL [0x91]:  IN=0x0000917F  OUT=0x0000D17F
//FAIL [0x92]:  IN=0x0000927F  OUT=0x0000D27F
//FAIL [0x93]:  IN=0x0000937F  OUT=0x0000D37F
//FAIL [0x94]:  IN=0x0000947F  OUT=0x0000D47F
//FAIL [0x95]:  IN=0x0000957F  OUT=0x0000D57F
//FAIL [0x96]:  IN=0x0000967F  OUT=0x0000D67F
//FAIL [0x97]:  IN=0x0000977F  OUT=0x0000D77F
//FAIL [0x98]:  IN=0x0000987F  OUT=0x0000D87F
//FAIL [0x99]:  IN=0x0000997F  OUT=0x0000D97F
//FAIL [0x9A]:  IN=0x00009A7F  OUT=0x0000DA7F
//FAIL [0x9B]:  IN=0x00009B7F  OUT=0x0000DB7F
//FAIL [0x9C]:  IN=0x00009C7F  OUT=0x0000DC7F
//FAIL [0x9D]:  IN=0x00009D7F  OUT=0x0000DD7F
//FAIL [0x9E]:  IN=0x00009E7F  OUT=0x0000DE7F
//FAIL [0x9F]:  IN=0x00009F7F  OUT=0x0000DF7F
//FAIL [0xA0]:  IN=0x0000A07F  OUT=0x0000E07F
//FAIL [0xA1]:  IN=0x0000A17F  OUT=0x0000E17F
//FAIL [0xA2]:  IN=0x0000A27F  OUT=0x0000E27F
//FAIL [0xA3]:  IN=0x0000A37F  OUT=0x0000E37F
//FAIL [0xA4]:  IN=0x0000A47F  OUT=0x0000E47F
//FAIL [0xA5]:  IN=0x0000A57F  OUT=0x0000E57F
//FAIL [0xA6]:  IN=0x0000A67F  OUT=0x0000E67F
//FAIL [0xA7]:  IN=0x0000A77F  OUT=0x0000E77F
//FAIL [0xA8]:  IN=0x0000A87F  OUT=0x0000E87F
//FAIL [0xA9]:  IN=0x0000A97F  OUT=0x0000E97F
//FAIL [0xAA]:  IN=0x0000AA7F  OUT=0x0000EA7F
//FAIL [0xAB]:  IN=0x0000AB7F  OUT=0x0000EB7F
//FAIL [0xAC]:  IN=0x0000AC7F  OUT=0x0000EC7F
//FAIL [0xAD]:  IN=0x0000AD7F  OUT=0x0000ED7F
//FAIL [0xAE]:  IN=0x0000AE7F  OUT=0x0000EE7F
//FAIL [0xAF]:  IN=0x0000AF7F  OUT=0x0000EF7F
//FAIL [0xB0]:  IN=0x0000B07F  OUT=0x0000F07F
//FAIL [0xB1]:  IN=0x0000B17F  OUT=0x0000F17F
//FAIL [0xB2]:  IN=0x0000B27F  OUT=0x0000F27F
//FAIL [0xB3]:  IN=0x0000B37F  OUT=0x0000F37F
//FAIL [0xB4]:  IN=0x0000B47F  OUT=0x0000F47F
//FAIL [0xB5]:  IN=0x0000B57F  OUT=0x0000F57F
//FAIL [0xB6]:  IN=0x0000B67F  OUT=0x0000F67F
//FAIL [0xB7]:  IN=0x0000B77F  OUT=0x0000F77F
//FAIL [0xB8]:  IN=0x0000B87F  OUT=0x0000F87F
//FAIL [0xB9]:  IN=0x0000B97F  OUT=0x0000F97F
//FAIL [0xBA]:  IN=0x0000BA7F  OUT=0x0000FA7F
//FAIL [0xBB]:  IN=0x0000BB7F  OUT=0x0000FB7F
//FAIL [0xBC]:  IN=0x0000BC7F  OUT=0x0000FC7F
//FAIL [0xBD]:  IN=0x0000BD7F  OUT=0x0000FD7F
//FAIL [0xBE]:  IN=0x0000BE7F  OUT=0x0000FE7F
//FAIL [0xBF]:  IN=0x0000BF7F  OUT=0x0000FF7F
```

I iterated though the conversions and come out with a range of conversions that don't work.  Basically if the 8th and 4th bits are set in the third byte, the 7th bit is always set after the conversion.

In other words
8* C* (80 doesn't do it as the error starts at 81)
9* D*
A* E*
B* F*

Comment: The second line prints `Special NaN: 0x0000A07F` for me (and no failed test conversions) - can you give us more details of what platform you're running on?

Comment: @JonSkeet I tested it and it fails for me, .net 4.5.2, Debug, AnyCPU, i7 2600k with Windows 10. Any difference with your setup?

Comment: Changing it from AnyCPU to x64 Platform in the Configuration manager seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Gusman: I was just compiling it from the command line with csc. Were you running it in the debugger, or standalone? That may be a difference...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm compiling from VS2017, I have tried Debug and Release, AnyCPU, x86 and x64 with the same results, even tried to run it directly from command line (no recompile, just run outside VS) and have the same results.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok, found it, it's the x86/x64 difference, VS still sets the "prefer 32 bits" even if you set it to x64, changing to x64 and unchecking the prefer 32 bits from the project options seems to work

Comment: Right, compiling with `/platform:x86` reproduces the issue.

Comment: Sorry for not including the platform information.  This is a legacy library I'm expanding so it's x86 against .Net Framework 4